# Do something if there are no results from chrome.tabs.query

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm aware that the function chrome.tabs.query will callback for every tab found matching the query parameters. I would like to execute some code though if there are no matching tabs. Is that possible, if so, how?

---

Ok, sorry, I was obviously confused as the assumptions I gave in my question were incorrect. The first answer has set me straight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't callback for every tab.

```
chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs){
 //tabs is an array and you can call array functions on it just like normal array
 if(tabs.length == 0){
  //do whatever
 }
})
```

Comment: forgot to mention you can also take off **== 0** because in javascript 1 == true and 0 == false so having tabs.length actually be 0 is just false